# Error executing tests in Travis CI with JaCoCo

Tags: java, maven, travis-ci, jacoco

I'm working on a Java proyect and I'm trying to generate some code coverage with JaCoCo. If I run my tests with Maven everything works fine, but my Travis build crashes with this error while trying to run my tests:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:513)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:525)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Class java/lang/UnknownError could not be instrumented.
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_c13123e.core.runtime.ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.createFor(ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.java:140)
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_c13123e.core.runtime.ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.createFor(ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.java:101)
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_c13123e.PreMain.createRuntime(PreMain.java:55)
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_c13123e.PreMain.premain(PreMain.java:47)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: $jacocoAccess
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:2000)
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_c13123e.core.runtime.ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.createFor(ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.java:138)
    ... 9 more
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
Aborted (core dumped)

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

My .travis.yml file is (logic is the package in which my tests are stored):

```
language: java
after_success:
 - bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
script: 
- "mvn -Dtest=logic/** test"
```

And my pom.xml file is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>TFG</groupId>
    <artifactId>TFG</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
                <skipTests>${skip.unit.tests}</skipTests>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
                        <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>post-unit-test</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</dataFile>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gestor</groupId>
            <artifactId>GestorProblema1maquina</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/GestorProblema1maquina.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.woodstock.dependlibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jhall</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: First running JUnit Jupiter you should use maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2 furthermore defining  provider is not necessary...also you should use only junit-jupiter-engine as dependency nothing else. I see you are using JUnit 4...my assumption is you are running JUnit 4 Test you have add vintage engine if you need to run them via JUnit 4...and finally you should use the most recent version of jacoco-maven-plugin 0.8.4 ....

Comment: What I missed. You should check the output of your travis build cause based on that setup you are running your build twice (https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/job-lifecycle/#skipping-the-installation-phase)...BTW: You have not defined which version of the JDK you would like to use on Travis?

Comment: Changing surefire and jacoco plugins versions worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to select concrete jdk version for builds (it helps me with the same error):

```
jdk:
  - openjdk8
```